# Python read UDP C# stream

Tags: python, udp

There is a server that sends UPD stream - 60 packets per second

I use twisted to read it:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import reactor
class Echo(DatagramProtocol):
    def datagramReceived(self, data, (host, port)):
        print ('1',data)
class Echo(DatagramProtocol):
reactor.listenUDP(port, Echo())
reactor.run()
```

In console I have like:

```
('1', '\xea\xb6|C\x00\x00\x00\x00gK\xa0E\x00O\x05\xbd\x97\xb7\x04B\xf6\xfdY@\xb9\xa8\x0cD\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004\x8e8\xbfKkv\xb3\xa6i1\xbf\xa6i1\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x004\x8e8?\xc0\x98\xed\xc1\xbd\x98\xed\xc1=\x1a\x9a\xc1\x96\x19\x9a\xc1\x9d\x88)\xba\x9fB,\xbaA\xb2\xa9;\xc5]\xd86\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x80\xcd\xcc\xcc=\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd4Q\x81@')
('1', '\x7f\xd5\x82D\x00\x00\x00\x00+8\x89Ed\xf0/\xbe\xbdy\x06D\x8b\xfaM@\xa9-ZD\x9f\x03EB\x89\xeb4\xc2Z+\x87\xbes\xf7\x9bAw\xc7\xca\xbeMv\x83\xbc\xc4\x07k\xbf\xd6\x06k\xbf\x93);\xbc\xd6\xe0\xca>m\xc4\xb5A\x7f\xdc\xd6A\xf7\x8arA!\xbdcAe\r\xb3B\xc4\xf7\xd3B*\\\xdeBWF\xe5B\xa5\xffBB\xddaCB\x8c EBL8EB\x00\x00\x807\x00\x00$\xbc\x00\x00\x807\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0@F\xc6\xb1=(O\x12\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x885\xa4D')
```

The person analyzing the traffic says: "The packet puts out through this contains the fields(38 different fields).  All fields are float datatype (in C#)"

I understand comes 38 numbers? Can I use Python to read them?

Comment: Can't you just ask that person what he or she meant?

Comment: Sending floating-point values in their binary form is a terrible idea. The best way is to convert it to a fixed-length string, and send that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module for that:

```
floats = struct.unpack('<38f', data)
```

(You *might* need to change the `>` to `<` depending on the endianness of your data.)